# Strange issue with ATTiny10 + avr-gcc: counter used in ISR corrupted by global variables?

Tags: attiny, avr-gcc

I have a very strange issue of a possible memory corruption when using global variables and a timer overflow interrupt on the ATTiny10 (using avr-gcc 4.9.2). I can't make any sense of it but managed to narrow it down to reproducing it with a very simple program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

/* Timer overflow counter */
volatile unsigned int ovrf = 0;

/* Some global variables used in main() */
/* (MOVING THESE INTO main() FIXES THE ISSUE) */
unsigned long foo;
unsigned int bar;

int main(void) {
  /* Fast PWM 8 Bit Mode */
  TCCR0A |= _BV(WGM00);
  TCCR0B |= _BV(WGM02);
  /* Enable Timer Overflow Interrupt */
  TIMSK0 |= _BV(TOIE0);
  /* /8 prescaler */
  TCCR0B |= _BV(CS01); // 
  /* PB0 as output */
  DDRB |= _BV(PB0);
  /* Enable interrupts */
  sei();

  for (;;) {
    /* Some random code that uses the global vars */
    /* (REMOVING THIS FIXES THE ISSUE) */
    if (foo > bar) {
      foo = 0;
    }
  }
}

ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect) {
  ovrf++;

  /* Toggle LED (about once per second) */
  if ((ovrf / 500) % 2 == 0) {
    PORTB &= ~(_BV(PB0));      
  } else {
    PORTB |= _BV(PB0);
  }
}
```

All it does is the following:

- Sets up the timer and a timer overflow ISR that increments a counter (global variable `ovrf`) and toggles an LED on and off based on the value of this counter.
- The main loop just accesses two other global variables (doesn't even write anywhere).

I'd expect the LED to blink periodically, proving that the interrupt works and the counter is incremented correctly. But it doesn't turn on -- or when modifying the program slightly, e.g. adding some more code in `main()` or more variables -- it flashes erratically or at a very fast rate. From this, after a lot of testing, trying to exclude any other explanation, I'm assuming that the counter (`ovrf`) is somehow getting corrupted from the main loop.

I found several changes that can make the issue disappear:

- moving the two global variables (`foo` and `bar`) into `main()`
- removing the code that accesses them
- changing the type of `foo` to `int`
- turning off all optimisations with `-O0` (the default was `-Os`), but this makes the code ~1.6x bigger.

But I still can't see any explanation about the actual cause. Am I completely missing something obvious...? I've run out of ideas and can't think of anything else other than a compiler bug, but that's very unlikely, given that this example is so simple.

**UPDATE**

Based on the suggestion from @MarkU I tried to play with various optimisation settings, trying to find the exact option that might cause the problem:

- Also tried `-O1`, but it doesn't help either
- I found that `-Os -fno-toplevel-reorder` *also fixes the issue!* -- However, I suspect this might just be an accidental effect:
- In my original program (very similar to the above simplified example), where I found the issue, *none of the above helps* (not even `-O0`). There I have one more global variable (a `bool`), and the only thing that seems to help is to *remove an initial assignment* (e.g. `"bool ledOn = true;" --> "bool ledOn;"`).

So it's definitely something to do with *how* variables are allocated, but not simply about their overall size. (There are no other dependencies, no function calls, etc.)

**UPDATE 2**

Following the advice from @Curd, I also tried replacing `ovrf / 500` with `ovrf >> 9` (rougly the same, I don't care about exact timing here anyway). This reduced the code by 74 bytes(!) -- and this *also happens to fix the issue!*

I had a look at the disassembled code for the ISR: this change reduces the number of bytes `pushed` at the beginning from 13 to 7, which could explain why it helps!

(This `ovrf / 500` was just meant to be a quick and simple test to verify the ISR was working, but I didn't realize that in actual implementation it's not that simple at all! In my original program there is no division, I maintain an approximate millis count by simply multiplying `ovrf` by 2.)

I also compared the disassembled code for `-Os` ("bad") and `-Os -fno-toplevel-reorder` ("good"), but apart from code being reordered at the beginning, both the contents of `main()` and the ISR seem the same (same number of pop/pushes, etc.)

--

It appears that I can fix the problem in this concrete example with one of the above workarounds, but I still feel uncomfortable with not really understanding the actual cause and not knowing how to avoid this in the general case. And I don't know enough about assembly to analyze the generated code.

Maybe I should also ask some of these questions:

- Is this kind of trial-and-error process "normal" when using C for the ATTiny10? (I mean: not nearly enough resources and/or insufficient compiler support to make this reliable - so don't expect it to work and just revert to assembly if it doesn't?)
- Is there something that should generally be avoided (e.g. not using global vars, or optimisation)?

**UPDATE 3**

Thanks for all the comments and answers, there is a lot of useful suggestions in them, worth checking all for anyone running into a similar problem!

I had one more "mystery" remaining with my original program where replacing a `bool ledOn = true;` with `bool ledOn;` was the only fix.

Now that I understand more, I had another look at the generated assembly and memory usage: turns out that the initialisation makes the compiler produce a `.data` segment and one more byte is allocated in memory, which is just over the limit to cause a collision with the stack. Although (I think) it uses a register for this variable at the end, just like in the "no explicit initialisation" case, so the extra allocation shouldn't be necessary. I guess the compiler has simply no optimisation for this extreme case with such small amount of RAM.

Comment: What does the disassembled code look like?

Comment: "changing the type of foo to int" is good starting point. it could be that your comparison operator produces type conversion code that messes up nearby data after been "optimized".

Comment: Examine the disassembled code, for both the `-O0` and `-Os` settings -- my guess is that one of the optimization flags (like `-fcaller-saves`?) clobbers the code that saves/restores the status or index registers within the interrupt service routine. See [Atmel ATtiny10 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8127-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny4-ATtiny5-ATtiny9-ATtiny10_Datasheet.pdf) section 5.8 Reset and Interrupt Handling. See also [gcc-4.9.2 optimization options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

Comment: What does your memory map look like? ATtiny10 has only 32 bytes of SRAM, with an unsigned, a long, and an int, (plus whatever overhead the c libraries and debugger claim), it must be getting crowded.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks! I'm afraid I'm not sure what to look for, I don't know much about assembly... I had a look at the output of `avr-objdump -D` and `-S` for the `.hex` and the `.elf` files, and I can see differences, some make sense, but I can't really follow what's going on. (Didn't want to post the whole output but happy to do that - or a portion of it if that helps!)

Comment: @Maple When I change *both* to `long`s, the issue is still there... so it's not that, but probably something about *accessing* these variables in the main loop. (I'm puzzled though, as I'm definitely not *writing* to anything there...)

Comment: @MarkU Thanks for the suggestion! I did some more investigation, see the update above. Memory map: sorry, I'm really a beginner in this area, where should I look for the memory map...? I'm not sure this is simply about trying to allocate too much memory, as I don't think any extra dependencies are included apart from the bare minimum, and I don't use a debugger.

Comment: @Maple correction (can't edit my comment above): by "not writing to anything" - I mean not writing to anything shared with the ISR - at least not intentionally...

Comment: @pdenes: do you know how many cylces it takes to evaluate `ovrf / 500`? The ATtiny doesn't even have an instruction for multipication; not to mention divison! This test can be implemented **much** more microcontroller-friedly. Maybe it takes more cycles to process the ISR than you have configured the timer interval. BTW: i don't see the timer intevrall initialized!

Comment: @Curd: Very good point! I tested this, see the second update above! Re timer interval: the default CPU frequency is 1Mhz and with a /8 prescaler and the 8-bit timer, the frequency of the overflow will be 1000000/8/256 ~= 488 Hz, which is consistent with what I'm seeing when it works correctly. (I don't think I need to initialize anything else, but I may have misunderstood something!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With only 32 bytes of memory (as mentioned by MarkU in a comment), memory on the ATtiny10 is *incredibly* tight. The AVR-GCC compiler does not provide any tools for stack checking, and will happily generate code which will overrun the stack. For example, here's what it generated for the prologue to your ISR:

```
000000ba <__vector_4>:
  ba:   1f 93           push    r17
  bc:   0f 93           push    r16
  be:   0f b7           in      r16, 0x3f       ; 63
  c0:   0f 93           push    r16
  c2:   10 e0           ldi     r17, 0x00       ; 0
  c4:   4f 93           push    r20
  c6:   5f 93           push    r21
  c8:   6f 93           push    r22
  ca:   7f 93           push    r23
  cc:   8f 93           push    r24
  ce:   9f 93           push    r25
  d0:   af 93           push    r26
  d2:   bf 93           push    r27
  d4:   ef 93           push    r30
  d6:   ff 93           push    r31
```

I count 13 `push`es in there. That'll make the stack expand to nearly half your device's memory alone. Combined with another `rcall` in the body of the ISR, as well as a couple of `push`es and `rcall`s in the prologue to `main`, the ISR stack will end up colliding with the memory used to store your global variables, overwriting them with unexpected data.

The ATtiny10 is not a good target for a C compiler. If your application can support a slightly larger microcontroller, upgrading to the tiny25/45/85 family might be warranted. Otherwise, I would recommend targeting this device with assembly.

Comment: Or judicious and careful use of [`ISR_NAKED`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Possibly, although if you aren't careful that'll just trade one set of problems (ISR causes stack collision) for another (ISR corrupts registers in use by `main()`).

Comment: I simulated his code and found that the stack pointer was going as low as RAM address $46 when calling the code to calculate ovrf/500 in the ISR, which was the same location as ovrf! With ovrf>>9 the stack pointer only went down to $4E.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Makes sense. Division is implemented by a call to a udivdi function; removing that call turns the ISR into a leaf function, whith might improve register allocation.

Comment: Thanks @duskwuff! I think this also answers my "follow up" questions about the validity of using C.

Answer (score 2):

```
volatile unsigned int ovrf = 0;
unsigned long foo;
unsigned int bar;
```

+8 bytes of ram

```
int main(void) {
```

+2 bytes or ram, use **attribute**((OS_main))

```
ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect) {
```

If you don't specify anything, it pushes a stackframe, for a function call. That will be around 14 bytes, if I recall correctly from my ATTiny10 struggles.
The return address (2 bytes), and some registers.

With only 32 bytes, you can do **one** full function call. If you want more, you'll need to use `__attribute__((naked))` and write assembler.

```
if ((ovrf / 500) % 2 == 0) {
```

This probably calls library functions, of which you can't store the stackframe.

And there is also only 1024 bytes of program memory. This is very small for C,
~100 lines small.